# Using firebase simplelogin facebook and angularjs to persist information to firebase

Tags: facebook, angularjs, firebase, firebase-security

If I use firebase's simpleLogin with facebook as provider to register and save user information to my firebase, will it not duplicate the entry if the user has already an entry on the database.

In my controller, but probably not the right place to register the user:

```
$scope.login = function(service) {
  simpleLogin.login(service, function(err, user) {
    $scope.err = err? err + '' : null;
    // on login what are you gonna do with the profile info
    // probably save a copy in firebase

  });
};
```

Should I save the user info in that function in my controller? Here is my login factory, because I have a hunch that saving the user should be done right here.

```
return {
  init: function() {
    auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef());
    return auth;
  },
  logout: function() {
    assertAuth();
    auth.$logout();
  },
  login: function(provider, callback) {
    // check if app is authorized, then login if yes
    assertAuth();
    auth.$login(provider, {rememberMe: true}).then(function(user) {
      if( callback ) {
        //todo-bug https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/199
        $timeout(function() {
          callback(null, user);
        });
      }
    }, callback);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends- if you are using "user" as part of your view, then bind it to the scope object in you controller. If not, create a local object called user in your factory, and refer to it there.